# How to implement Firebase Messaging to Xamarin.Android application?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android

I am making my Android application using Xamarin.Android.
I want to implement push notifications, I am trying to do it with Firebase following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows
However this guide and others on the same topic seems to be outdated. When I create a new project in Firebase Console and click add to android application i see instruction for Android Studio, Unity and Web application. No instruction for Xamarin. When i try to follow instruction for Android Studio i can get google-services.json file but i cant follow part 3 and 4 (Adding android SDK and Testing connectivity) because they are for gradle development. 
How use Firebase Cloud Messaging in Xamarin.Android application or Is there any other way to add push notifications for my application?

Update:

I downloaded new google-services.json file from Firebase Console -> Settings to my project, cleaned the solution, rebuild it and deleted app from device. When I test app on a device and click on Log Token Button the token in Log Output is empty, after that it gives me: 
D/FirebaseInstanceId(14477): background sync failed: TIMEOUT, retry in 10s. 
So now i cant get the Token, or maybe I cant refresh it.

I checked the following:

- Package name of my project match the package name on Firebase app
- google-services.json Build Action is set to GoogleServicesJson
- Google Play Services is available on my device(Samsung SM-A500F Android 6.0 API 23), I also tested this on other devices and still not working

I'm dealing with this problem a long time, if you need any other information, please ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the Microsoft example you mentioned and I had the same problem.
Searching in another example, I found out there's a class missing in the code so here it goes.

Just make sure it's next to the MyFirebaseIIDService class in the root of the Android project. That solved my problem.

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);

        var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
        var title = message.GetNotification().Title;
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + body);
        SendNotification(body, title, message.Data);
    }

    void SendNotification(string messageBody, string Title, IDictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                                  .SetContentTitle(Title)
                                  .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                  .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }


}
```

Comment: Hmm.. all of that code is in the linked document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows#foreground-notifications

Answer (score 1):

All you need from the Firebase console is the google-services.json file. Once you have that, ignore the instructions linked from the firebase console and use the Microsoft instructions document that you linked, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

In the firebase console, do make sure that the package name in firebase console matches the package name of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I downloaded new google-services.json file from Firebase Console -> Settings to my project, cleaned the solution, rebuild it and deleted app from device. When I test app on a device and click on Log Token Button the token in Log Output is emply, after that it gives me: D/FirebaseInstanceId(14477): background sync failed: TIMEOUT, retry in 10s. So i cant get the Token

Comment: This might require some deeper investigation. You can open a free Xamarin email support case to work one on one with a Xamarin support engineer. You can open a free Xamarin support case here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16068&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636645150473349054